# Creating array with function and returning its name in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, scope

I am trying to create a function that generates empty arrays.

Problems:

1. I don't know how to show the name of the array in `console.log`.
2. how to make the array and array's name accessible in a global scope

```
function arrayCreator (arrName){
    arrName = [];
    console.log(arrName.name() + ' : ' arrName); 
}
```

P.S. `arrName.name()` doesn't work, of course. It is more like a placeholder.

Comment: Arrays don't have names. *Variables* (and properties) have names. What do you really want `arrayCreator` to do?

Comment: Its not a variable name, its value

Comment: If the names are important, you probably want an object containing arrays like `{name: [], name2: []}`

Comment: the name of the variable the array is assigned to is what you pass as an argument to your function...so just `arrName` would be the name of the array

Comment: Would be a good time to help us help you by reading through [ask] then expanding on your use case for all of this. What you have currently is known as an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Not quite @LegenJerry -- the function repeatedly assigns the variable `arrName` *not* the string passed in.

Comment: Like @MarkMeyer stated it would make more sense to have the function store the arrays in an object that’s defined in global scope. Then you can access the properties of that object which would be your array names

Comment: @LegenJerry best to refrain from comments like your "silly" one. Question has problems in it yes....but I'm sure OP is also struggling with a real issue and just needs some guidance which is the purpose of this site. How to ask for help also has a learning curve. Trivializing others issues does nothing positive

Comment: @charlietfl I'm here to help, i've included a possible solution to his problem

Comment: Guys, I know, that question might looks funny or something like this for people, who know JS good. For me, it is problem, that I can't solve so far. And it is not XY problem, because the ultimate goal of this function is learning and understanding javascript.

Comment: @Vasulevus I apologize for my comment. I am here to help. I provided an answer that may solve your problem. Good luck!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is one possible implementation that may achieve the result you want. The function stores the arrays in an object. You can access the array names on a global scope using `Object.keys(myobject)` . Of course I just made a loop to create some random array names and call the function multiple times. I'm not sure how your application will be getting array names.

```js
var arrObject = {};
function arrayCreator (arrName){
    arrObject[arrName] = [];
}

for( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  arrayName = "myArray" + i;
  arrayCreator(arrayName);
}
console.log(arrObject);
console.log(Object.keys(arrObject));
```

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow. Thank you for help anyway.